# Rc car, power supply instead of alkaline battery?

Tags: batteries, converter, alkaline

I have an RC car which works with 8 AA alkaline batteries, which make a total of 12 volts.

I want to replace the battery with a 12v 2A power supply (batteries cost away too much...)

Do you think the 2 A of my power supply are enough ?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, AA batteries fairly well never have a capacity >2.7Ah (usually 1.8-2.3Ah), so as long as your pack of series-connected AAs lasts >1hr in use, then you're for sure safe.

EDIT: At very worst, the 12V/2A power supply might yield a small reduction in initial power vs. the batteries, but should for most purposes be sufficient.

Comment: at worst, my ac dc converter would get hot and fry, right? no damage the the car?

Comment: I doubt it would even cause significant damage to the ac adaptor, unless you really flog it by keeping the car at max. output for extended periods, and that only if the car actually eats >2A (which isn't all that likely, anywise).